# Vulnerabilities found in npm@9.6.6 which is latest version in strip-ansi

Tags: docker, npm, node-modules, npm-vulnerabilities

I had a long list of vulnerabilities after deploying my npm project on the docker container but after changing OS I am left with only one vulnerability related to npm which [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/omu4Y.png)is strip-ansi.
It is inside the npm package only when I run the npm list command.

I am having different versions of strip-ansi in my dependency tree and the latest version is "7.0.1".
I am attaching the dependency tee image also.
Could anyone help me in resolving this issue?

I had tried overrides and npm fix resolutions and many more things but nothing is working.